# OCR A Image Using Microsoft office document imaging library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image

how to ocr a colour image using MODI. I have converted a .tif image that i created using Paint and got text from that but it is not working with colour images.How to process a colour image so that i can extract text from that.

I used this code for ocr

```
 MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();
            md.Create(@"c:\test3.tif");
            md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, false, false);
            MODI.Image img845 = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
            TextBox1.Text = img845.Layout.Text
```

;

Answer (score 0):

You can create grayscale image first by such method

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile("oldFile"));

for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    {
        Color color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
        int grayScale = (color.R + color.G + color.B) / 3;
        bmp.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale));
    }
}

bmp.Save("newFile");
```

and then do OCR on new file, which is grayscale

Comment: I converted the image to greyscale but still it is not working. when i try to extract characters from the grayscaled image its showing an exception "OCR Running error"

Comment: Try to do it black&white, but it's very strange. I did a OCR with this library on colored picture and everything was OK.

Comment: i tried by making the image black&white but no use. The image actually had some noises in it.Is that creating problem i dont know

Answer (score 0):

You need OCR engines for that, there are couple available free on the internet, some are paid. There is a tool - eFlow built in .NET which works like that.